# Implementing a Set in typescript, specifically IterableIterator<[T, T]>

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, iterator, iterable

I'm playing with a Set implementation in typescript. I want it to adopt the interface of set, but with some differences, I seem to have a problem with: `entries()` however:

I have implemented `next()` on my object, which returns either:

```
{
 value: elementAt(index),
 done: false;
}
```

or

```
{
value: undefined,
done: true
}
```

but this does not work for

`entries() : IterableIterator<[T, T]>`

and I can't seem to find any references for how to do this. Can someone help out here? My first thought was that the value of value has to be different but so far nothing i have tried has worked.

Comment: why `[T,T]`? that means iterating should produce a list of 2 elements? shouldn't you just be implementing `IterableIterator<T>`?

Comment: Why not see what a built-in `Set` does? `const s = new Set([1, 2, 3]); Array.from(s.entries()).forEach(v => console.log(JSON.stringify(v))); // [1,1] [2,2] [3,3]`

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation of `Set.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/entries):

> The **`entries()`** method returns a new `Iterator` object that contains **an array of `[value, value]`** for each element in the `Set` object, in insertion order. For `Set` objects there is no key like in `Map` objects. However, to keep the API similar to the `Map` object, each *entry* has the same value for its *key* and *value* here, so that an array `[value, value]` is returned.

That means for your object to satisfy the `Set` interface, it needs to return a different iterator for its `entries()` method than it does for its `values()` and `keys()` methods. Specifically you need to make the `value` of the iterator result be a pair, so `next()` returns something like

```
{
 value: [elementAt(index), elementAt(index)]
 done: false;
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That's something like what I thought, but it doesn't work. Actually I believe it's supposed to return an element with a next method, that returns the object you specified. But that does not work either.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it’s hard to say what “does not work” means.

Comment: Absolutely, and I will try and add that, just haven't had the time today

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented (extended) the Set interface in an abstract class. In my case, I wanted users to define their own (extended) implementations of the abstract methods.

I delegated most things to the `_values` set, and so I didn't have to mess with a lot.

VS Code completed most of this (it helps you with methods to implement). I Googled a bit to find a `foreach` implementation.

At the bottom is an example of how to instantiate the new class with the methods.

```js
/** Wrap a Set to support multiple values, 
    e.g., foos are objects in a set, but each foo has an "opposite" */
export abstract class SetWithOpposite<T> implements Set<T> {

    abstract setOpposite(value: T) : this
    abstract clearOpposite(value: T) : this

    add(value: T): this {
        if (!this._values.has(value)) {
            this._values.add(value)
            this.setOpposite(value)
        }
        return this
    }

    constructor(iterable?: T[]) {
        this.clear();

        if (iterable === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        if (!Array.isArray(iterable)) {
            throw new Error("Non-array iterables not supported.");
        }

        for (const value of iterable) {
            this.add(value);
        }
    }

    clear(): void {
        this._values.clear()
    }

    delete(value: T): boolean {
        if (this._values.has(value)) this.clearOpposite(value)
        return this._values.delete(value)
    }

    forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, value2: T, set: Set<T>) => void, thisArg?: any): void {
        for (const element of this._values.keys()) {
            callbackfn.call(thisArg, element, element, this);
        }
    }

    has(value: T): boolean {
        return this._values.has(value)
    }

    get size(): number {
        return this._values.size;
    }

    entries(): IterableIterator<[T, T]> {
        return this._values.entries()
    }

    keys(): IterableIterator<T> {
        return this._values.keys()
    }

    values(): IterableIterator<T> {
        return this._values.values()
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T> {
        return this.values()
    }

    [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;

    _values = new Set<T>()

}
```

Client defining and using a concrete implementation of `SetWithOpposite`:

```js
import { SetWithOpposite } from "./setWithOpposite";

const incomingAccesses = new class extends SetWithOpposite<String> {
    setOpposite(value: String): this {
        console.log(`setOpposite: ${value}`)
        return this
    }
    clearOpposite(value: String): this {
        console.log(`clearOpposite: ${value}`)
        return this
    }
}

let entity = new String('Fred')

incomingAccesses.add(entity)

entity = new String('Nancy')

incomingAccesses.add(entity)

incomingAccesses.forEach(element => {
    console.log(`foreach element: ${element}`)
});

incomingAccesses.delete(entity)

for (const entry of incomingAccesses) {
    console.log(entry)
}
```